# Combine different Machine Learning Models into a single meta-ML model

Tags: r, metamodel

I am trying to combine signals from different Machine Learning models to create a Single Meta Machine Learning Model . I have two datasets(`df1, df2`) with different features(`df1 = x1, x2 & df2 = z1, z2`) which predicts the same output(`y`).

The reproducible example is as following

```
library(caret)
   df1 <-
  data.frame(x1 = rnorm(200),
             x2 = rnorm(200),
             y = as.factor(sample(c("bob", "bill"), 200, replace = T)))

df2 <-
  data.frame(z1 = rnorm(400),
             z2 = rnorm(400),
             y = as.factor(sample(c("bob", "bill"), 400, replace = T)))

library(caret)
check_1 <- train( x = df1[,1:2],y = df1[,3],
                 method = "nnet",
                 tuneLength = 10,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                          classProbs = TRUE,
                                          savePredictions = T))

check_2 <- train( x = df2[,1:2],y = df2[,3] ,
                 method = "nnet",
                 preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                 tuneLength = 10,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                          classProbs = TRUE,
                                          savePredictions = T))
```

How do I combine both model into a single Meta Machine Learning Models? There is one close answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423696/how-to-combine-two-machine-learning-algorithm-outputs) which ensembles the models. However, my problem is combining the output from different training set and combine into **Single Meta Machine Learning Model**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensemble different datasets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725934/ensemble-different-datasets-in-r). You are asking for 95% almost the same question here.

Comment: The dataset used are the same but the question is different. I would be grateful if you can answer in the current question context.

Comment: having different training datasets and trying to predict  something is difficult. Is the test / new data related or  can the train data somehow be combined into one table? What I mean is, that when you predict an outcome, can it be related to both sources? So if we have a dataset where we predict Bill based on check_1, is there an ID that we can use to compare what we predict with check_2? So check_1 predicts Bill, check_2 predict Bob, but an ID can tell us we are trying to predict the same answer?